# How to export the CRM customization programmatically

Tags: dynamics-crm

How can we export the customization of all the entities programmatically .

Or get the metadata of the Entity forms dynamically

Answer (score 1):

[Here's a sample from the SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb959414.aspx):

```
// Set up the CRM Service.
CrmAuthenticationToken token = new CrmAuthenticationToken();
// You can use enums.cs from the SDK\Helpers folder to get the enumeration for Active Directory authentication.
token.AuthenticationType = 0; 
token.OrganizationName = "AdventureWorksCycle";

CrmService service = new CrmService();
service.Url = "http://<servername>:<port>/mscrmservices/2007/crmservice.asmx";
service.CrmAuthenticationTokenValue = token;
service.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

// Create the request.
ExportAllXmlRequest request = new ExportAllXmlRequest();

// Execute the request.
ExportAllXmlResponse response = (ExportAllXmlResponse)service.Execute(request);
```